# Parse JSON in Microsoft SQL

Tags: json, sql-server, parsing

I have the following JSON, 
And I have no clue as to how to parse "Value" (When you run it in SQL you get 3 columns key, value and type)

Any ideas?

```
       DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json = N'[
  {"salesDate":"2020-03-02","storeSales":[
{"storeId":"104","sales":[
{"productId":"20002","salesVolume":0.700,"salesQuantity":2,"lastChanged":{"date":"2020-03-03","time":"07:28:06"}},
{"productId":"74301","salesVolume":0.750,"salesQuantity":1,"lastChanged":{"date":"2020-03-03","time":"07:28:06"}},
{"productId":"642401","salesVolume":0.750,"salesQuantity":1,"lastChanged":{"date":"2020-03-03","time":"07:28:06"}},
{"productId":"784001","salesVolume":2.100,"salesQuantity":3,"lastChanged":{"date":"2020-03-03","time":"07:28:06"}},
{"productId":"1013801","salesVolume":1.500,"salesQuantity":2,"lastChanged":{"date":"2020-03-03","time":"07:28:06"}},
{"productId":"1202801","salesVolume":0.750,"salesQuantity":1,"lastChanged":{"date":"2020-03-03","time":"07:28:06"}},
{"productId":"1209901","salesVolume":0.700,"salesQuantity":1,"lastChanged":{"date":"2020-03-03","time":"07:28:06"}},
{"productId":"1282201","salesVolume":0.750,"salesQuantity":1,"lastChanged":{"date":"2020-03-03","time":"07:28:06"}},
{"productId":"3317301","salesVolume":1.500,"salesQuantity":2,"lastChanged":{"date":"2020-03-03","time":"07:28:06"}},
{"productId":"4801301","salesVolume":0.700,"salesQuantity":1,"lastChanged":{"date":"2020-03-03","time":"07:28:06"}},
{"productId":"5780106","salesVolume":6.000,"salesQuantity":2,"lastChanged":{"date":"2020-03-03","time":"07:28:06"}},
{"productId":"7964902","salesVolume":0.375,"salesQuantity":1,"lastChanged":{"date":"2020-03-03","time":"07:28:06"}},
{"productId":"10785001","salesVolume":0.750,"salesQuantity":1,"lastChanged":{"date":"2020-03-03","time":"07:28:06"}},
{"productId":"11037501","salesVolume":1.500,"salesQuantity":2,"lastChanged":{"date":"2020-03-03","time":"07:28:06"}}]}]}]';

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
```

[image: SQL Image]

Comment: @Kane provided a solid answer.   May I suggest that you show your appreciation for his time and talent by ACCEPTING the answer.

Comment: I did and the flag is green,  long live to Citizen @Kane

Comment: I saw that  and gave you a plus one as well  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you wanted to get the sales data try this (although I am not 100% sure if this query offers the best performance)

```
SELECT [SalesDate], [StoreId], [ProductId], [SalesVolume], [SalesQuantity]
FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH (
        [SalesDate] DATETIME '$.salesDate',
        [StoreSales] NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.storeSales' AS JSON
    )
    OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(StoreSales) WITH (
        [StoreId] INT '$.storeId',
        [Sales] NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.sales' AS JSON
    )
    OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(Sales) WITH (
        [ProductId] INT '$.productId',
        [SalesVolume] DECIMAL(18, 4) '$.salesVolume',
        [SalesQuantity] INT '$.salesQuantity'
    )
```

Comment: Just one small tweak    SELECT SalesDate,StoreId,ProductId,SalesVolume,SalesQuantity   Either way +1

Comment: Actually, it may be helpful for the OP to visualize how this works by keeping SELECT *

Answer (score 0):

`Value` is the first object in your JSON array, which is itself another JSON object. SO you will have to read it using other SQL Server JSON utilities.  For example:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(Value, '$.salesDate')
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
```